# WebDriver getCurrentUrl() returning malformed URI

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, uri, url-encoding, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm involved in writing a (Java/Groovy) browser-automation app with Selenium 2 and FireFox driver.

Currently there is an issue with some URLs we find in the wild that are apparently using *bad* URI syntax. (specifically curly braces (`{}`), `|`'s and `^`'s).

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl(); // http://example.com/foo?key=val|with^bad{char}acters
```

When trying to construct a `java.net.URI` from the string returned by `driver.getCurrentUrl()` a `URISyntaxException` is thrown.

```
new URI(url); // java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index ...
```

*Encoding* the whole `url` before constructing the `URI` will not work (as I understand it).

The *whole* url is encoded, and it doesn't preseve any pieces of it that I can parse in any normal fashion. For example, with this uri-safe string, `URI` can't know the difference between a `&` as the query-string-param delimeter or `%26` (its encoded value) in the content of a single qs-param.

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8") // http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%3Fkey%3Dval%7Cwith%5E%7Cbad%7Ccharacters
URI uri = new URI(encoded)
URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, "UTF-8") // []
```

Currently the solution is, before constructing the `URI`, running the following (groovy) code:

```
["|", "^", "{", "}"].each {
    url = url.replace(it, URLEncoder.encode(it, "UTF-8"))
}
```

But this seems dirty and wrong.

I guess my **question** is multi-part:

1. Why does FirefoxDriver return a String rather than a URI?
2. Why is this String malformed?
3. **What is best practice for dealing with this kind of thing?**

Comment: It's not clear - do you really have those bad characters in URL and you expect them? Could you add an example of a string you expect to see and you actually get? Thanks.

Comment: Due to the nature of the project, I cannot confirm if the *actual* urls are different from what WebDriver is reporting, nor am I able to share too many specifics, but `http://example.com/foo?key=val-with-a-|-in-it` __is__ indicative of what we actually see returned from `driver.getCurrentUrl()` in rare cases.

Comment: another example I just dug up: `http://example.com?foo={bar}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can partially encode query string parameters, as discussed in comments, it should work.

Other way is to use [galimatias](https://github.com/smola/galimatias) library:

```
import io.mola.galimatias.GalimatiasParseException;
import io.mola.galimatias.URL;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        String example1 = "http://example.com/foo?key=val-with-a-|-in-it";
        String example2 = "http://example.com?foo={bar}";

        try {
            URL url1 = URL.parse(example1);
            URI uri1 = url1.toJavaURI();
            System.out.println(url1);
            System.out.println(uri1);

            URL url2 = URL.parse(example2);
            URI uri2 = url2.toJavaURI();
            System.out.println(url2);
            System.out.println(uri2);
        } catch (GalimatiasParseException ex) {
            // Do something with non-recoverable parsing error
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/foo?key=val-with-a-|-in-it
http://example.com/foo?key=val-with-a-%7C-in-it
http://example.com/?foo={bar}
http://example.com/?foo=%7Bbar%7D
```

Comment: Not super excited to add a dependency on what appears to be a somewhat obscure library, but so far this looks like the best solution.

Comment: Answer from Rameshwar is actually better, no additional library :)

Comment: see my comment on his answer. In short, his way won't work using this library will.

Answer (score 0):

driver.getCurrentUrl() gets a string from the browser and before making it into an URL, you should URL encode the string.

See [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) for an example of this in Java.

Comment: It's my understanding that doing this will turn `http://example.com/foo?key=val|with^|bad|characters` into `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%3Fkey%3Dval%7Cwith%5E%7Cbad%7Ccharacters`, which isn't the behaviour I'm looking for. I'll test this just to be sure, but I think that URI will not take this string in its contructor

Comment: Yea, as suspected, this will not work. If I create a `URI` with this encoded String, I cannot parse it or do anything with it. I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @ZachL I think this answer is correct, but you should encode only query string part. In your question you show that you encode the whole URL, which is incorrect.

Comment: hmmm... well the answer seems to imply that I should encode the whole string, which is wrong. I could perhaps take the whole query string after the `?`, split this on the `&`'s and `=`s, encode those chunks, and put the url back together. If you want to write this up as an answer (or @dming wants to edit his answer as such) I will mark that as correct and award bounty if no better solution appears.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String urlInString="http://example.com/foo?key=val-with-a-{-in-it";
    String encodedURL=URLEncoder.encode(urlInString, "UTF-8");

    URI encodedURI=URI.create(encodedURL);
    System.out.println("Actual URL:"+urlInString);
    System.out.println("Encoded URL:"+encodedURL);
    System.out.println("Encoded URI:"+encodedURI);

}

}
```

Output:

`Actual URL:http://example.com/foo?key=val-with-a-{-in-it
Encoded URL:http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%3Fkey%3Dval-with-a-%7B-in-it
Encoded URI:http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%3Fkey%3Dval-with-a-%7B-in-it`

Comment: Doesn't compile (replace uri1 with urlInString), also URLEncoder.encode(String) is deprecated, you need to use URLEncoder.encode(String, "UTF-8")

Comment: Thanks you @sap1ens. Updated the code according to your suggestions. Code should compile now.

Comment: How is this different than the approach in my question where I use `URLEncoder`? This looks like the same exact thing, with the same issue.

Comment: Your approach `URI encodedURI=new URI(uri1); ` is generating the error `// java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index ...` . But I used `URI encodedURI=URI.create(encodedURL);` which is giving the output that I have shown. Is that output that you were looking for?

Comment: This has the same problem as [@dming's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29017513/363701), and my example using `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")` (where no error occurs). In this case, I cannot analyze the URI like I need to. For example: I need to be able to do `uri.getQuery()` and retrieve the query string as it is in the wild: `?key=val-with-a-{-in-it`. With the *galimatias* library I can get it as such. In your code this returns `null`. When `http://` gets encoded it becomes `http%3A%2F%2F` making it not parse correctly as a URI. The same is true for `?`, `&` and `=` in the query string.

Comment: @ZachL Does your domain name (I mean `http://example.com/`) remain constant always?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74939/discussion-between-rameshwar-and-zach-l).

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution is to split the URL fetched and then use them to create the URL you want. This will ensure that you get all the features of URL class.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;     
import java.net.URISyntaxException;      
import java.net.URL;

public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
        URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
    String uri1 = "http://example.com/foo?key=val-with-a-{-in-it";

    String scheme=uri1.split(":")[0];

    String authority=uri1.split("//")[1].split("/")[0];

    String path=uri1.split("//")[1].split("/")[1].split("\\?")[0];  

    String query=uri1.split("\\?")[1];  


    URI uri = null;
    uri = new URI(scheme, authority, "/"+path, query,null);

    URL url = null;

    url = uri.toURL();

    System.out.println("URI's Query:"+uri.getQuery());
    System.out.println("URL's Query:"+url.getQuery());

}

}
```

Comment: this is definitely a possible approach, but a bit more heavy handed than I'd like, and I think I'd default to using the `replace` method in my original post. For this code to work, I'd have to make it significantly more robust to deal with things that may not have a path or query string.